# pole and essential singularity in the same point

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

In this case [image]

in $0%$ i have an essential singularity by $\sin(\frac{1}{s})$
but i have a ""pole"" too ( the denominator of the fractions $\frac{(...)\sin(...)}{**S**}$) , so in this case is this a pole or is this an essential singualrity and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an essential singularity.

An essential singularity is characterized by an infinite number of negative degree terms in its Laurent series expansion. So the $\frac{1}{s}$ contribution, which has only one such term (namely $\frac{1}{s}$ itself), plays no role.

Comment: it's because the laurent series of the sin is 1/s-6/s^3+120/s^5  so if i multply by 1/s it will became 1/s^2-6/s^4+120/s^6 etc so it will always have infinite negative power of s so it is still an essential singularity , right ? @ndweolf

Comment: Yes exactly. No matter what you do, it remains an essential singularity

Comment: even if the s was in the numerator like $[ s(s+1)\sin(\frac{1}{s}) ]$? the grade will just be minor ( 1-6/s^2+120/s^4) but still an essential singualrity ? @ndweolf

Comment: Indeed, you would at most remove a term of degree -2, but as there are an infinite number of negative degree terms it would still remain an essential singularity.

Comment: i will remove terms of degree -2 beacuse s(s+1) is of 2 degree ?

Comment: Yes indeed. Suppose the Laurent series contains the terms $\frac{a}{s} + \frac{b}{s^2}$. By multiplying with $s(s+1)$ you obtain $a(s+1) + b + \frac{b}{s}$. So the term with degree -2 is removed. However to remove the essential singularity this way you would have to multiply by a polynomial with degree $\rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: Thk you so much

Answer (score 1):

It's an essential singularity. That's because the Laurent expansion at $0$ has infinitely many nonzero terms in the singular part (the terms with negative powers of $z$).

Comment: ahh beacuse i have something like 1/s-6/s^3+120/s^5 so multipling it by 1/s it just increase by 1 the power of the denominator so it always have infinite negative powers of z , right ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right (I guess you mean multiplying by 1/s, not 1/2)

Comment: and it would be the same if the s was up in the numerator ? ( 'cause i will have always infinite negative power of s ( but this time the s at numerator decrease the order , but still they are infinite negative power) so always an essential singularity , right ?

Comment: (in the first comment i wrote 1/2 i made a mistake i wanted to write 1/s but i think you have understood that)

Comment: Yes. You can see from this that if $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$, then multiplying $f$ by any rational function (not identically zero, of course) will not change that. I think that you could also say that multiplying $f$ by any holomorphic or meromorphic function (not identically zero) will not change that.

Comment: thk you so much :)